# how to unzip and render svg file uploaded via Wordpress and zipped by cloudfront?

Tags: wordpress, svg, amazon-s3, mime-types, amazon-cloudfront

My .svg image file was uploaded in WP media library as `image/svg+xml`.  Cloudfront has compressed this file and when I reference it in html it won't render as an image but instead Chrome prompts me to download it.

***My .htaccess:***

```
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

***Amazon S3 properties, metadata:***

```
content-type: image/svg+xml
content-encoding: gzip
```

Only `content-type` was manually set after uploading from WP.  I had to clear the cloudfront cache after changing the content-type since it originally cached it with type set to `mime/type` (even if it was already correctly set in Wordpress).  *I'd like to avoid this manual process for other the images but that's a worry for later.*

***html code:***

```
<p>This renders</p>
<img src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/mydrawing.svg" width="300px" height="300px" alt="blabla">

<p>This doesn't render</p>
<img src="http://a9txahw87b8uam.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/mydrawing.svg" width="300px" height="300px" alt="blabla">
```

***functions.php:***

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');
function custom_upload_mimes ( $mimes=array() ) {
    $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml'; // this causes cloudfront zipping
    //$mimes['svg'] = 'mime/type'; // this doesn't cause cloudfront zipping
    return $mimes;
}
```

**Settings for WP Plugin: Offload S3:**

- Domain: Cloudfront domain
- Copy Files to S3: ON
- Rewrite File URLs: ON
- Object versioning: OFF

**Questions**:

1. I'm aware that Cloudfront will zip files of content type `image/svg+xml`. But the problem is that the viewer isn't unzipping it.
2. If I upload the .svg file to WP as `mime/type` then it is never zipped and it renders.  But is that the right way? It doesn't feel right and it makes it impossible to set that image as a *featured image* in a blog post.

Any help in solving or understanding the problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: CloudFront does not "zip."  It's gzip.  Those are two incompatible things.  If you have the content already gzipped and `Content-Type` set to `gzip` in the S3 metadata, then CloudFront should not modify the content further, and if it does, that's a big bug in CloudFront, which seems very unlikely.  If the content is already gzipped but `Content-Type` isn't set accordingly then it won't work, but not for the reason you expect.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html says that CloudFront will compress files with image/svg+xml in the header.  Which is why (I think) it leaves the file alone if I upload it to WordPress as mime/type.  Furthermore, the file is 155kb in WP but 28kb in the Amazon bucket.

Comment: I edited the text to clarify: it was not me that set `content-encoding` value.  I only set the `content-type`.

Comment: I should have done it before instead of assuming, but Michael's comment led me to check Cloudfront's settings. turns out automatic compression of (certain) files is set to OFF.  So I must conclude that the compression came from the WP plugin, and not at all from Cloudfront.

Answer (score 0):

It works now (all I did was refresh my browser for the first time since yesterday).  I think it was an unknown caching issue.

I say *unknown* because I cleared the cache in CloudFront (created an invalidation) and also on my browser.

I also did a small test by uploading an svg file directly to the S3 bucket and another via WP (via the Offload S3 plugin) as usual.  The latter is compressed, the former not.  But both render.